# Checking responses ranges for HTTP 206 responses for videos

Tags: javascript, html, http, amazon-cloudfront

I'm serving some HTML5 videos over Amazon CloudFront. They're being requested with HTTP range requests and the responses are often `HTTP 206 Partial Content`, as expected.

I'd like to log, with Javascript, the ranges requested and the ranges in the response (i.e., bytes `0-` requested, bytes `0-1000` responded). Is this possible? Keep in mind these isn't an `XMLHttpRequest`; it's just a `<video>` tag. I already have a client-side logging facility, but I don't know how to get the data I need.

CloudFront already logs the number of bytes in the response, unfortunately including headers too, but I need to also know how many bytes were requested. There's one Safari user who made tens of thousands of range requests for a single 500 KB video and transferred more than 1 GB as a result, and I can't figure out why.

Some other options and their drawbacks:

- Use the Safari developer tools. They're useless to me because they don't show the HTTP status code for requests generated by `<video>` tags. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻
- Use Wireshark. This seems completely unpredictable and unreproducible, so unless I have the user capture packets during the entire testing cycle--which would be a massive capture--I can't isolate the data to specifically when the problem occurs. It's a last resort.
- Use EC2 to act as a proxy so I can have finer control over logging (i.e., I can log the raw `Range` request header and the response headers). It can work for a testing environment if I'm ever able to reproduce this, but not for production because I need the benefits a CDN like CloudFront provides.

Comment: Is asking your problematic user to open the developer tools not an option? (Preferences->Advanced->Show Developer Menu to enable) — I don't believe it's possible to intercept requests made by standard elements like `<video>` using JavaScript directly. The best you could manage would be to use the `progress` event listener to see how quickly the data reaches the client (potentially showing you if there's a particular stall point or if it's being generally slow)

Comment: During this testing phase I can ask for developer tools, but I can't ask this of production use, so I'm hoping for a solution that can work with both. And fun fact: Safari doesn't show the HTTP status code for <video> requests.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest debugging one-on-one if you find specific issues like this, and raising a feature request with AWS for the long-term monitoring need (it seems like a very reasonable requirement, and I can see they already capture a variety of other headers in their logs). This is the sort of thing which is much better handled at the server-side than the client-side.

Comment: Also you may want to consider setting up a small EC2 instance to serve test content (where you would have full control over the logging), and asking anyone who has problems to load the test video (e.g. in an invite-only locked-down section).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Taken directly from the above link:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

Just link/bind the above to your html button and you can do whatever you want with the response (both the actual video file or the error - if one is returned).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not apply here; the OP stated "Keep in mind these isn't an XMLHttpRequest; it's just a <video> tag"

Comment: Correct. This is not requested by Ajax, nor am I using jQuery. Also, in addition to knowing that a HTTP 206 Partial Content was the response, I need to know precisely what byte range was requested and what byte range was in the response.